Scroll Controller Attached To Multiple Scroll Views
we have two flows
showing items in two places in home screen and cart -> templates->list of items
we are reusing the items screen in both cases for that we are using the ScrollController
but we are gettng the error like Another exception was thrown: ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views. how to get rid of it
I have tried dispose and reinitialize it on every navigation to over come that issue.

can you include simple code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue? possibly you just need to provide a ScrollController or you can do primary:false if it has this param
